# how to update user model connection if a specific APP_ENV is set

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

Currently setting up a sandbox to mirror my live environment but I need the users tables connection to be set to something else if my APP_ENV is set to "live"

Now ideally in the user model i would love to do something like:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
    public function __construct()
    {
        if (\App::environment('live')) {
            protected $connection = 'ot20';
        }
    }
```

But that is not the case. Any ideas on how I go about this?

Citti

Comment: is there a way to extend the user model where i could actually do a comparison based on APP_ENV ... similar to how I have done it with passport? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#overriding-default-models

Answer (score 0):

`$connection` is a normal class property so you can simply set it to a new value:

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
    public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);

        if (\App::environment('live')) {
            $this->connection = 'ot20';
        }
    }
```

About your comment: I'm not clear what you mean but you can create a custom user model and tell Laravel to use that instead by setting the `providers.users.model` in `config/auth.php`.

Comment: interesting. Getting a " "message": "Undefined variable: connection", " however.

Comment: What's the stacktrace? Your `__construct()` implementation should accept the same parameters as the parent method (`array $attributes = []`) and call it with `parent::__construct($attributes)`.